# Разница в поведении на \n у windows server и mac os

Tags: java, строки, файлы

Есть код который пишет лог в `txt` файл:

```
@Override
public void report(String currentDeposit, String serviceName) {
    String report = String.format("%s | %s | %s\n", LocalDateTime.now().format(dtf), serviceName, currentDeposit);
    int userNum = TimeListener.getShift().getUserNum();
    String path = String.format("%s/report/User_%s_Report.txt", new File(".").getAbsolutePath(), userNum);
    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get(path), report.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Как видно из кода в конце переменной `report` есть `\n`, для того что-бы каждая следуючая запись была c новой строки. И на машине на `Mac OS` где ведется разработка, все отрабатывает корректно. Но при переносе на тестовый стенд, где стоит `Windows Server` внезапно выснилось что переноса строки не происходит и все записи идут одной строкой.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что это может быть, и как сделать так, чтобы лог писался не в одну строку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `System.getProperty("line.separator");` вместо `\n` 
Можно объявить отдельно `String endl = System.getProperty("line.separator");` 
 И использовать как знак переноса строки.
Эта функция возвращает подходящий к системе перенос строки, если так можно выразится

Answer (score 1):

Также вы можете использовать System.lineSeparator
Этот вариант,  а также предложенный выше,  "подгружает" символы новой строки динамически,  во время выполнения программы,  возвращая символы,  которые используется той системой,  где программа запускается. 
В вашем случае: вы используете "\n",  это новая строка в Mac. На Windows используется другая строка переноса,  "\n\r", если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: как раз на Mac это \n, на винде \r\n